# Unity Input Debugger stick Vector2 value is not zero

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, joystick

[image: ProblemImage]

i have a device we made.
i connected with Unity via bluetooth.
and i saw Unity Input Debugger stick value is not zero.
there are three cases here.

1. Unity 21.3.10f1 Window Platform - device bluetooth connect
2. Unity Window Platform - device USB cable connect
3. Android APK - device bluetooth connect
   case 2 and 3 is working good, Input Debugger stick value is zero.
   but only case 1 is not.

Please help me..

i tried `InputSystem.ResetDevice(connectedJoystick, true)` but it doesn't work.